# How can I see which AuthorizeAttribute Failed ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to work out if there is an easy way to get ASP.NET Core to log which `[Authorize]` attribute is failing. I have a mixture of "Role" and "Policy" authorize attributes but whenever a single one fails the logs just show:

[image]

Obviously this is the correct behaviour and it doesn't let someone in with incorrect permissions however if you have multiple attributes it's a bit of a pain to have to go and work out which one failed. If the log simply showed `Authorization failed for Policy X` then that would be really easy to then find what's failing.

Does anyone know if it's currently possible to make this happen through some option I'm unaware of?

**EDIT:** For example: If I had `[Authorize(Policy = "Policy 1")]` and `[Authorize(Policy = "Policy 2")]` and only "Policy 2" failed. I would like to see something that tells me that it was "Policy 2" that failed.

**EDIT:** For anyone still coming across this question this has now been implemented by Microsoft and is part of .NET 5.0, see issue https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7789

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `Roles` and `Policy`, they are translated to requirements like `RolesAuthorizationRequirement` or your custom requirement like `MinimumAgeRequirement`.

For `Authorization failed.`, this is logged by `DefaultAuthorizationService` in `AuthorizeAsync`, you may not able to get the exact name like `Policy 1` and `Policy 2`. You could get the requirements for `Policy`.

Try to check whether workaround below meets your requirement.

1. Implement custom `DefaultAuthorizationService`

   ```
   public class CustomAuthorizationService : DefaultAuthorizationService, IAuthorizationService
   {
       private readonly AuthorizationOptions _options;
       private readonly IAuthorizationHandlerContextFactory _contextFactory;
       private readonly IAuthorizationHandlerProvider _handlers;
       private readonly IAuthorizationEvaluator _evaluator;
       private readonly IAuthorizationPolicyProvider _policyProvider;
       private readonly ILogger _logger;

       public CustomAuthorizationService(IAuthorizationPolicyProvider policyProvider
           , IAuthorizationHandlerProvider handlers
           , ILogger<DefaultAuthorizationService> logger
           , IAuthorizationHandlerContextFactory contextFactory
           , IAuthorizationEvaluator evaluator
           , IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options) 
           : base(policyProvider, handlers, logger, contextFactory, evaluator, options)
       {
           _options = options.Value;
           _handlers = handlers;
           _policyProvider = policyProvider;
           _logger = logger;
           _evaluator = evaluator;
           _contextFactory = contextFactory;
       }

       public new async Task<AuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, object resource, IEnumerable<IAuthorizationRequirement> requirements)
       {
           if (requirements == null)
           {
               throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(requirements));
           }

           var authContext = _contextFactory.CreateContext(requirements, user, resource);
           var handlers = await _handlers.GetHandlersAsync(authContext);
           foreach (var handler in handlers)
           {
               await handler.HandleAsync(authContext);
               if (!_options.InvokeHandlersAfterFailure && authContext.HasFailed)
               {
                   break;
               }
           }

           var result = _evaluator.Evaluate(authContext);
           if (result.Succeeded)
           {
               _logger.LogInformation($"Authorization is succeeded for { JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requirements) }" );
               //_logger.UserAuthorizationSucceeded();
           }
           else
           {
               //var r = result.Failure.FailedRequirements.Select(requirement => new { Requirement = requirement.GetType() });
               var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Failure.FailedRequirements);
               _logger.LogInformation($"Authorization is failed for { json }");
               //_logger.UserAuthorizationFailed();
           }
           return result;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Replace built-in `DefaultAuthorizationService`

   ```
   services.AddAuthorization(config =>
   {
       config.AddPolicy("T1", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
   });

   services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IAuthorizationService, CustomAuthorizationService>());
   ```

Comment: Thanks Tao, Looks like this moves in the correct direction. Still a shame the name of the policy isn't available for evaluation here.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft are implementing this by default in .NET 5.0, see the related GitHub issue for details and links to PR.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7789

Answer (score 0):

you can handle and log this inside `Middlewares`

```
public class AuthHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> _logger;

    public AuthHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IHostingEnvironment env /* other scoped dependencies */)
    {  

        await _next(context);

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
           _logger.LogInformation($"'{context.User.Identity.Name}' is unauthorized");
    }
}
```

In your starup config,

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ... )
{
      ....
      app.UseMiddleware<AuthHandlerMiddleware>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer the question. I am not interested is the "user" that failed, I am interested in the "policy" that failed (or other condition). Your proposed solution leaves the exact same issue, what was the condition that caused the failure.